# Swagger -> Doctrine (PHP) -> MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine-orm, swagger-2.0

I need to create a RESTful Web Service in PHP and picked up the awesome SLIM framework.

Then I was exploring different options and picked up
 * Swagger for REST API Definition and it can generate SLIM PHP Code.
 * Doctrine 2 for ORM.

Now I need to know is there way to upgrade the Model PHP classes generated by Swagger to Doctrine Entities, with the DocBlock annotations. So I can then generate the MySQL tables from there.

Or if it is possible to create MySQL tables directly from the Swagger generated Model classes or somehow with Swagger definition itself, then I can generate Doctrine Entities from the DB.

Any help would be appreaciated :-)